# Is there a way to preserve or remember sort-by preferences for different folders in column view in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, finder, sorting, osx-leopard

For example, I would like to have folders in **column view**, and to have Folder 1 always to show files sorted by kind, and Folder 2 always to show files sorted by date created. I'm running Leopard, with upgrade to Snow Leopard available but not installed.

Comment: FWIW, if you're using list view it works just as you'd like in Mac OS X 10.6

Comment: Interesting. I typically use column view though--does that also preserve the individual settings across different folders?

Comment: Column View is an all or nothing proposition. All of the visible folders in your browser are sorted using the same arrangement. However opening a new window with a different folder will read that folder's defaults.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Column View is an all or nothing proposition. All of the visible folders in your browser are sorted using the same arrangement. However opening a new window with a different folder will read that folder's defaults. – Chealion Oct 28 '09 at 4:54

Answer (score 2):

In Yosemite (at least), there is a squirrely way to preserve the sort order for a folder in the Column View. First save the folder's sort order in the List View as described in this thread. When you next re-enter this folder in the Column View, click on List View and then back to Column View. Voila! The sort order from the List View is used for the Column View.

This only works if you want the same sort order for both Column View and List View for this folder, but if you always wish to view the folder in Column View, then this isn't a problem. Somewhat of a pain to have to switch twice, but at least the saved setting can be quickly recalled.

Answer (score 0):

You can set view options for individual folders by (when Finder is active) either pressing <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> or "View>>Show View Options..." to open Finder's "View Options" Dialog. In this dialog you can change properties like e.g. the sort policy, icon size, or grid spacing.

If your goal is to apply the settings for each folder on an individual basis you should avoid pressing the "Use as Defaults" button, though.

The settings are applied immediately and (after committing the dialog) every time you open that folder in the Finder again.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't let individual folders preserve different preferences. If I am in Folder 1 and tell it to sort by kind, and then I go to folder 2 and set it to sort by date created, then when I go back into Folder 1, it's still sorted by date created.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question but on my computer this works as described.

Comment: Mine will also do this in list view, but not in column view. I should have been more specific.

Comment: There is no "use as defaults" button in the options for column view. (Confusingly it took me FOREVER to realize that you get different view options when you toggle the view type).